# Using subquery to pull random value reveals same value every time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I want to add a random value to a column in a query using T-SQL for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. To do this, I use a subquery and pull a random record. Every time I run the query, it pulls a new random record, but the value for every row is identical.

How can I get a new random value for each row?

Sample query:

```
SELECT column1,
    (SELECT TOP 1 column1 as c2 FROM Table2 ORDER BY NewID())
FROM Table1
```

Whereas table2 looks like

```
column1
value1
value2
value3
```

It always returns the same value for column2, instead of a new random record for each table.

First run:

```
column1, c2
1, value1
2, value1
3, value1
```

Second run:

```
column1, c2
1, value2
2, value2
3, value2
```

How can I get c2 (the subquery) to pull a new random record for each row?

Ideal scenario:

```
column1, c2
1, value2
2, value1
3, value2
```

Comment: You probably need to reference the outer query so SQL Server thinks it is correlated. This will be quite inefficient though. What is the requirement here?

Comment: Thanks @PeterSchofield, I meant 2008 r2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT column1,
    (SELECT TOP 1 column1 as c2 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.column1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY NewID())
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I'm going to guess this is the highest performing option, since it doesn't require any text parsing functions. Thank you.

Comment: Same goes for an update statement. eg. `update table set fkId = (select top 1 id from otherTable order by newId()`, would be `update t1 set fkId = (select top 1 t2.id from otherTable t2 where t1.col = t2.col order by newId() from table t1`

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
SELECT T1.column1,
    (SELECT TOP 1 column1 as c2 FROM Table2 ORDER BY NewID(), LEN(T1.column1))
FROM Table1 T1
```

To force it to re-evaluate the selection each time. This will be very inefficient though. Also quite fragile (without the `LEN` it didn't work!) Would it meet your requirement to sort the T2 values randomly once (or possibly more if Table1 is larger than Table2) then join by row_number?

The main difference I can see with the methods is that your current method will allow the same random row to be selected multiple times my proposed method wouldn't.

Comment: Inefficient is just fine for this situation, so this should work perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for the mention of re-evaluation; this is at the heart of the matter and makes this the best answer.

Comment: works great, and slow as advertised :)
but should the len function not rather be the second column to order by? ordering by the length of an int first, and random second creates an interesting pattern of clustered randomization, certainly not the optimum distribution.

Comment: @dlatikay - yes I agree